# AngularJS 1 factory error unknowwn provider

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to get the data from a json file.

i have a file, factory1.js

```
myApp.factory('mainInfo', [
'$http',
  function($http) {
  return {
    get:  function(){
        $http.get('data.json'); 
    }
}}])
```

and then i have another file, view1.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.view1', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/view1', {
    templateUrl: 'view1/view1.html',
    controller: 'View1Ctrl'
  });
}])

.controller('View1Ctrl', [

  '$scope',
  '$http',
  'mainInfo',

  function($scope, $http, mainInfo) {
    mainInfo.get("data.json")
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
        console.log($scope.myWelcome)
    });
}]);
```

i have one folder with each of the json, factory and controller files in it.

when i run this the error it is returning says...

```
angular.js:13708 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: mainInfoProvider <- mainInfo <- View1Ctrl
```

where am i going wrong?

Comment: set this > var myApp = angular.module('myApp.view1', ['ngRoute']).........

Comment: that because your factory setup by myApp Module and your main module is not var

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working fine. This solves your problem i hope so.

```
 'use strict';

    var app=angular.module('myApp.view1', ['ngRoute'])

    app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.when('/view1', {
        templateUrl: 'view1/view1.html',
        controller: 'View1Ctrl'
      });
    }])


app.factory('mainInfo', 
  function($http) {
  var obj={};
    obj.method =function(){
       return $http.get('tag.json')

}
    return obj;
  })
app.controller('View1Ctrl', [

  '$scope',
  '$http',
  'mainInfo',

  function($scope, $http, mainInfo) {
    mainInfo.method().success(function(response) {
        $scope.myWelcome = response;
    });
}]);
```

Comment: hey, I tried this but now `mainInfo.get($http)` is coming back as `undefined`

Comment: Now you can see the edited version above i tested this here is the plnkr https://plnkr.co/edit/Lf6QcyKSn4DsQrgJhUq6?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

```
var app=angular.module('myApp.view1', ['ngRoute']);

app.factory('mainInfo', [
'$http',
  function($http) {
  return {
    get:  function(){
        $http.get('data.json'); 
    }
}}])
```

define one variable and assign your module to that variable and bind the variable to the factory.if you have module with name myApp inject that module in to myapp.view1 module 
like

```
angular.module('myApp.view1', ['ngRoute','myApp'])
```

Comment: hey, I tried this but now it's saying `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

Comment: obviously it will...... you need to store the response somewhere....just refer to $http in angular docs

 $http.get('data.json').success(function(respose){
console.log(response);
});

Answer (score 1):

Register mainInfo inside Angular module, if it's a different module.

view1.js

```
angular.module('myApp.view1', ['ngRoute', 'myApp']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not assigned your module to a variable.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp.view1', ['ngRoute']) ...
```

Then use myApp.factory

```
myApp.factory('mainInfo', [...
```

see [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/YgsbWmJDsRSAJ4YSsXZo?p=preview) for quick understanding.